# Radio button label background color when checked (using contact form 7)

Tags: html, css, contact-form-7

I'm trying to make the background color of my label changing when I click on my radio button.
However I've tried a lot of solutions that other people have tried, but it seems to doesn't work with my code.

Here the code I have in my CF7 :

```
<div class="custom-button">
<input type="radio" id="monsieur" name="radio-genre" class="genre radio" value="monsieur" />
<label id="label1" class="custom-label" for="monsieur">Monsieur</label>
<input type="radio" id="madame" name="radio-genre" class="genre radio" value="madame" />
<label id="label2" class="custom-label" for="madame">Madame</label>
</div>
[select genre "Civilité" "Monsieur" "Madame"]
[text* last-name class:champ-text placeholder "Nom*"]
[tel* phone class:champ-text placeholder "Téléphone*"]
[email* email class:champ-text placeholder "Email*"]

[response]

[submit class:envoi-devis class:particuliers "Envoyer ma demande de contact"]

</div>
```

I have got some CSS to style the form, but the important one is :

```
input[type=radio]:checked + .custom-label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I've tried also ~ instead of the + sign but still not working.
Tried also to add a class in JS to the label with an onclick, but same.

If you have any tips, I would be grateful (Sorry if I made some mistakes in my english, it's not my native language)

Comment: I just tried this and it appears to work OK. Check either radio button and the label background turns red... what is the problem?

Comment: It litteraly doesn't work on my site ...
Maybe something overwritting the setting ?

Comment: `"Maybe something overwritting the setting"` - that does seem likely

Comment: Ok so I did test in VS code, indeed it was working, but on Wordpress (we're using Elementor Pro to add custom css), with no other code on the page, it is not working

Comment: use the console tools inspector to look for 404 - not found or other issues when loading the page. Ensure that paths are correct

Answer (score 0):

Not intended as an answer - this is simply to illustrate the css works as expected.

```css
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-button">
  <input type="radio" id="monsieur" name="radio-genre" class="genre radio" value="monsieur" />
  <label for="monsieur">Monsieur</label>
  <input type="radio" id="madame" name="radio-genre" class="genre radio" value="madame" />
  <label for="madame">Madame</label>
</div>
</div>
```